# How to link .dll library with the C++ VS project?

Tags: c++, visual-studio, dll

I want to use existing library (only .dll, not .lib) with the corresponding header file in my  C++ project. I changed these settings: `Project > Config. Settings > C/C++ > General > Additional Include Directories > Path\to\my\DLL`, but it seems that this is not the right way. I also tried change some linker settings. I use new Visual Studio Express.
Thanks.

Comment: You don't need to link it during build (compile & link) time. That's the whole idea behind DLL. It is a *Dynamically Linked Library*, which means that it is linked to your executable image **during runtime**. Just make sure that the DLL resides alongside your executable file.

Comment: I understand... but when I include only header file the compilation is aborted with this message: unresolved external symbol. I think because there is only function declaration and not definition(?)

Comment: Ahhh... You still need to link **the lib** file into your project.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need a reference to the .lib file corresponding to the DLL. The Lib file is basically a set of symbols that allows the linker to resolve the dependencies. It kinda stands in place of the DLL for the linker.

Comment: There is only .dll and header file. I try to use this library: [http://ufal.mff.cuni.cz/morphodita/](http://ufal.mff.cuni.cz/morphodita/).

Comment: Looks like you might have to build it yourself. See http://ufal.mff.cuni.cz/morphodita/install#toc2

Comment: Do I really have to compile it on my own and produce .lib file? It sounds horrible for me (under Windows :)

Comment: Well it shouldn't be too bad. You have GCC? The instructions are there. Although you might be able to ask the guys who build the windows DLL to give it to you. It should be generated whenever they build the DLL.

Comment: I have made the .lib with mingw32-make. Thanks a lot.

Answer (score 1):

According to [this MSDN article](http://support.microsoft.com/kb/131313) (it is quite old, but the steps should still work), you need to

a) Use DUMPBIN /EXPORTS <.DLL file name> to obtain the list of exported symbols for the .DLL
[you should be able to run DumpBin from your Visual Studio command prompt]

b) Create a .DEF file that contains an EXPORTS section with the names of the functions; see [here](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/28d6s79h.aspx) for an explanation of the .def file layout; [this link](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/d91k01sh.aspx) has an example of how a .def file looks like

c) Use LIB /DEF:<.DEF file name> to generate the .lib file

Comment: Another alternative would be to use [LoadLibrary](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ms684175(v=vs.85).aspx) and [GetProcAddress](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ms683212(v=vs.85).aspx) to call the DLL functions dynamically without linking to it.

Comment: Yes, it looks like an solution that I can also use. Thanks.